# Simulación vacía

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy intentando simular n veces un conjunto de datos aleatorios y al pasar este código solo me devuelve NA. Supongo que me falta añadir algo en algún lugar, pero no consigo ver dónde. Adjunto código por si alguien puede echarme un cable. Muchas gracias.

Primero creo función para generar datos, luego para añadir valores faltantes a este conjunto de datos, aplico imputación múltiple y obtengo los valores que me interesan.

```
create.data <- function(beta = 1, sigma2 = 1, n = 50,
                        run = 1) {
  set.seed(seed = run)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  y <- beta * x + rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(sigma2))
  cbind(x = x, y = y)
}

#Next, we remove some data in order to make the data incomplete. Here we use a simple random missing data mechanism (MCAR) to generate approximately 50% missing values.

make.missing <- function(data, p = 0.5){
  rx <- rbinom(nrow(data), 1, p)
  data[rx == 0, "x"] <- NA
  data
}

#We then define a small test function that calls mice() and applies Rubin’s rules to the imputed data.

test.impute <- function(data, m = 5, method = "norm", ...) {
  imp <- mice(data, method = method, m = m, print = FALSE, ...)
  fit <- with(imp, lm(y ~ x))
  tab <- summary(pool(fit), "all", conf.int = TRUE)
  as.numeric(tab["x", c("estimate", "2.5 %", "97.5 %")])
}

#The following function puts everything together:
simulate <- function(runs = 10) {
  res <- array(NA, dim = c(2, runs, 3))
  dimnames(res) <- list(c("norm.predict", "norm.nob"),
                        as.character(1:runs),
                        c("estimate", "2.5 %","97.5 %"))
  for(run in 1:runs) {
    data <- create.data(run = run)
    data <- make.missing(data)
    res[1, run, ] <- test.impute(data, method = "norm.predict",
                                 m = 2)
    res[2, run, ] <- test.impute(data, method = "norm.nob")
  }
  res
}

res <- simulate(1000)

apply(res, c(1, 3), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en un subset dentro de la función `test.impute()`.

```
test.impute <- function(data, m = 5, method = "norm", ...) {
  imp <- mice(data, method = method, m = m, print = FALSE, ...)
  fit <- with(imp, lm(y ~ x))
  tab <- summary(pool(fit), "all", conf.int = TRUE)
  as.numeric(tab["x", c("estimate", "2.5 %", "97.5 %")])
}
```

En la última línea de esta función se hace un subset por filas sobre el data.frame `tab`, buscando coincidencias con el valor `"x"`. Pero ese objeto no tiene nombres de fila (row names), por lo que no encuentra la fila `"x"` y entonces regresa `NA`. Eso procesado más adelante produce los `NaN`.

La solución que encontré es dirigir el subset directamente a la columna `term`, en la que sí podemos encontrar un valor igual a `"x"` y hacer el subconjunto.

Quedaría así:

```
test.impute <- function(data, m = 5, method = "norm", ...) {
  imp <- mice(data, method = method, m = m, print = F)
  fit <- with(imp, lm(y ~ x))
  tab <- summary(pool(fit), "all", conf.int = TRUE)
  as.numeric(tab[tab$term == "x", c("estimate", "2.5 %", "97.5 %")]) #Esta es la única línea que cambia. 
}
```

El resto del código queda igual y el resultado es una matriz numérica sin `NaN`. Creo que el resultado que se obtiene es el que buscas: comparar en una tabla las pendientes y los intervalos de confianza de las pendientes con dos métodos de imputación.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @mpaladino, uno de mis errores efectivamente venía de eso! Me ha quedado bastante claro con como me lo has descrito, el único fallo que me sigue dando es que parece que la función simulate no está creándome el resultado y sé que es mucho pedir, ¿pero ves algo raro en el código de esa parte? El error que devuelve es Error: object 'res' not found, pero la función que por lo tanto no funciona, simulate, no le veo nada raro y no entiendo por qué no genera resultado :_(

Comment: Ya lo corregí. Cuando lo estaba testeando cree uno de los objetos intermedios y le cambié el nombre y lo dejé así en el código que pegué aquí. Ahora debería funcionar, hice el test con un entorno vacío y funcionó.

Comment: De nuevo mil gracias! Este tema es nuevo para mí y tus comentarios me han ayudado muchísimo!!